# Regex match next

Tags: python, regex

I am having a problem with writing a regex to match name and if the name is followed by page containing a number it should match both.

First example won't match the page because the regular expression finds | which is lazy.

```
name|(?:,page(\d+))/

name/
name,page1/
```

Second example will match name and page number but it wont match name solely:

```
(?:name)(?:,page(\d+))/
```

I don't have any more ideas so far or I did not notice right expression special characters.

Could someone give me some hints in fixing this :)?

Edit:
I did come up with that solution:

```
name(,page(\d+))|name/
```

Comment: Shouldn't a simple `name(,page(\d+))?/` work as intended?

Comment: @Efrin: `?:` is for not capturing a group and `?` after selector is for making it 'optional'. Looks like you got the two mixed up.

Comment: Note, the `|` is the OR operator, so in your first regex it will match `name` OR `(?:,page(\d+))/`

Comment: @rednaw I noticed that | won't work as I wanted because as I mentioned "| won't match the page because the regular expression finds | which is lazy"

Comment: well, in regular expression world, with the term "lazy" you mostly mean when a `*` or `+` is appended with a `?`, (like `*?` and `+?` that makes the `*` or `+` stop as soon as possible, which is referred to as "lazy". The `|` operator doesn't have anything to do with lazyness.

Comment: `A|B` is lazy in the sense that if the pattern `A` matches, `B` is not tried, even if it would produce a longer match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the optional operator...

```
name(?:,page\d+)?\/
```

`(?:,page\d+)` is a non capturing group and `?` means that it can appear 1 or 0 times.

See [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/lQ9xU4).

Comment: That works. I don't know if have any experience with django but is it possible to treat "name" as *arg or **kwarg?

Comment: @Efrin Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that and I have no experience with django.